# Sencha Touch FireEvent from view is not being received in Controller

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have this defined in my view:

**View:**

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.Welcome", {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.welcomeview',


    config: {
        ///...items... removed lines for brevity.. 
        {
           xtype: 'button',
           id : 'btnSignInNow',
           text: 'Sign In Now',            
           listeners: {
               tap: function() {
               this.fireEvent("onSignInNowTap", this);
                console.log("onSignInNowTap fired"); /// <-- I see this in console.log
          }
       }
    }
```

I can see this in the log.  But in my controller it is not receiving the event. Can anybody shed any light on this?

**Controller:**

```
 config: {
        refs: {
            welcomeView: 'welcomeview'
        },

        control: {
            welcomeView: {
                onSignInNowTap: function () {
                    alert('bla!');  <!-- I Don't see this in console.log
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I appreciate I might have missed something, but is there any way that I can debug to find out how/where this event is being lost or ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your view's  listeners inside initialize,
you will get reference to **this** in the initialize

```
 Ext.define("MyApp.view.Welcome", {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.welcomeview',



 initialize:function(){
        this.callParent();
       listeners: {
          tap: function() {
             this.fireEvent("onSignInNowTap", this);
             console.log("onSignInNowTap fired");
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: The listener is ok, it is already on the button inside the view. I can see the console.log showing it calling the fireEvent. The problem is receiving the event in the controller. Please see my updated example (the listener is actually on the button).

Comment: yeah listener is ok.. but if you want reference of **this** , add items in initialize using `this.add([items])` and write any listeners.. one more thing use `scope:this` for function called after tap.

Comment: ok, I think I understand now. Could you change your example to show where the scope:this is used?

Comment: I got it! Tap becomes an object with 2 members (fn & scope). Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
this.parent.fireEvent("onSignInNowTap", this);
```

instead of

```
this.fireEvent("onSignInNowTap", this);
```

that way parent view will be firing event instead of button.
Sometimes if button is nested deep inside you might have to do something like this

```
this.parent.parent.parent....fireEvent("onSignInNowTap", this);
```

Comment: Ok cool, I didn't know you could do this.  I'll try this next time.

Comment: `this.parent.parent.parent....fireEvent("onSignInNowTap", this);` :: Apt solution , helped me twice :-)

Comment: You can also use `up()` to reach parent like this `this.up('#parentId').fireEvent("onSignInNowTap", this);`. This is more clean if you can query parent using its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ThinkFloyd. Your solution worked. I had to to use this.parent.fireEvent(...) and then the controller was able to catch it...